# fuse preview: getting build error when using Foreign(Language.ObjC)

Tags: fusetools

I'm adding a native iOS module to my fuse project, and tagging the native methods with [Foreign(Language.ObjC)], like this:

```
public class MyModuleIOS
{
    [Foreign(Language.ObjC)]
    public void Init(string token)
    @{
        // ...
    @}
}
```

When I run fuse preview from command line I get the following build error:

```
ERROR: Failed to compile .NET type MyModuleIOS: Statement type not supported in bytecode backend: ExternScope
```

Thanks for any suggestions for how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run the local preview. ObjectiveC will only run on ios device or simulator. You can add `extern(ios)` on your class so you only compile it on ios. Then you will also neeed one implementation for .net in preview though. [Here](https://github.com/fusetools/fuse-samples/tree/master/Samples/ForeignAccelerometer) is an example of foreign code.